# Split the collection into several parts

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to split the collection into several parts, taking an example from the documentation

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);

$chunks = $collection->chunk(4);

$chunks->all();
```

I want to get this

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

But I get this

```
[
  [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
  ],
  {
    "4": 5,
    "5": 6,
    "6": 7
  }
]
```

I get strange output data, although everything is fine in the documentation

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Definitely looks like a bug, since it doesn't match the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind this seems to be in the way the `chunk()` function in Laravel calls the `array_chunk()` [under the hood](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/daf094441404d0c51084abb6c03a64da1391a798/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php#L1289) with the third parameter set to `true`.

If you don't necessarily need to use collections and an array would be enough, this seems to do the trick:

```php
  $arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  $chunks = array_chunk($arr, 4, false);
```

The code above results in

```php
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
```